# Cannot Dissolve this Shapefile

Tags: qgis, dissolve

QGIS 2.18.11

This is not a question as such, but certainly something which I would learn from if resolved. I have [uploaded a shapefile of polgyons](https://ufile.io/8ufck) from multiple layers all merged into one. I have made sure the features are singleparts, checked validity of the geometry (which checks out) but still spits out an empty output. I've been trying to select half the features and dissolve twice to reduce the pressure put on the algorithm. I have tried v.dissolve but the same result occurs when using `vector>geoprocessing tools>dissolve`...just an empty output.

Comment: i tried with gdal (ogr) dissolve polygons in processing tools within qgis with your shapefile and it runs

Comment: Brother could be that version that is giving that error, my advice is to use version 2.14 Essen that is the most stable regards

Comment: So it does, I had obviously not tried dissolve with GDAL/OGR but it seems to be superior to the other dissolve methods! Thank you